# Running Vitest Issue: "[TypeError]: [postcss] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')"

Tags: laravel, webpack, postcss, vitest

In a Laravel 9 project, using Webpack Mix and Vue for frontend, a TypeError occurs during frontend testing with vitest:

```
TypeError: [postcss] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
    at getTailwindConfig (/Users/user/Repos/project/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:132:62)
    at /Users/user/Repos/project/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js:21:92
    at /Users/user/Repos/project/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/processTailwindFeatures.js:38:11
    at plugins (/Users/user/Repos/project/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/index.js:33:58)
    at LazyResult.runOnRoot (/Users/user/Repos/project/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:339:16)
    at LazyResult.runAsync (/Users/user/Repos/project/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:393:26)
    at LazyResult.async (/Users/user/Repos/project/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:221:30)
    at LazyResult.then (/Users/user/Repos/project/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:206:17)
```

This happened after a postcss.config.js file was added to the root of the project:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  }
}
```

This is my Vite config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    test: {
        globals: true,
        environment: 'happy-dom',
        coverage: {
            reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html'],
            reportsDirectory: 'vitest-coverage',
            include: [
                'resources/**',
            ]
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../resources')
        },
    },
})
```

I need to stop the error from showing up, but I don't want to delete or edit the postcss.cofig.js file in the root of my project.

Comment: I know this isn't a solution, but wanted to share that this seems like the same issue https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity/issues/3884 - seems there's some shennanigans with where to place postcss config files. If you're running tests inside a subdirectory where postcss can't find a config file, that might cause this issue